# How to make a 100% width website?

Tags: containers

I want to achieve a site like this

http://thebraveman.de/

it appears that their is no wrapper on this website, usually i put everything in a wrapper, how do i go about making a site width 100% within a wrapper ?

Answer (score 1):

With css:

```
html{
     padding:0;
     width:100%;
}

body{
     padding:0;
     width:100%;
}

.your-wrapper{
     width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I understand the body{..}, but what's the html{..} for?

Comment: I forgot if html required width to be 100%.  I will check and change my answer accordingly.